# How to get DUID on Tizen tablet?

Tags: tizen

How to get a DUID for Tizen tablet. 
Connection Explorer - Device - Properties didn't get such information:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

As I know DUID is not standard specification of Tizen.

It is served only Gear devices.

You can get it with following command.

```
sdb shell /opt/etc/duid-gadget
```

`/opt/etc/duid-gadget` is not in specification of Tizen. so it can be changed in any time. (But currently it works in Gear S, S2)

---

update:

```
The DUID of recent mobile and wearable devices start with a 2.0# but old devices are 1.0#. If a distributor certificate contains a 1.0# DUID, all devices with that certificate need one more step, see the Permit device to install apps guide.
```

As a current Samsung developer site, DUID can start with "1.0#" or "2.0#"
But in my gear device if you put any string after `duid-gadget` DUID changed to "2.0#"

```
sdb shell /opt/etc/duid-gadget
```

it print out `1.0#Ex1e7gjyXb4APXye6vQXiY=` but

```
sdb shell /opt/etc/duid-gadget anystring
```

will print out `2.0#Ex1e7gjyXb4APXye6vQXiY=`

I think maybe old device (like samsung gear 1 or 2) can get only "1.0#" DUID but I suggest to try to get "2.0#" DUID because "2.0#" DUID is easier to use than "1.0#". (you did not process "permit device process" wih "2.0#")

Answer (score 6):

Start Device Manager, connect to your device, right click it in device list and select DUID.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thansk a lot. This is it.