# Get a unique ID for each tizen device

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I'm a developing an application for the Tizen wearable devices.
I need to have a unique ID for each device to uniquely represent each device. Currently, I'm only able to get the Tizen ID with `tizen.systeminfo.getCapability("http://tizen.org/system/tizenid")` API. But this is only a randomly generated string and seems to be changing every time the device is reset. Each device has a unique ID in the form of DUID (See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40071954/7743702) here). But it looks like there are no APIs available to get this one programmatically. So is there any way I could access this DUID by an API or anything or is there any other unique ID which I could access programmatically?

Comment: So far I know, no availability of such functionality till now.

Answer (score 0):

You can get imei(meid) numbers from telephony and use them as a unique ID. IMEI stands for International Mobile Equipment Identity and is a unique identifier for a mobile device.

Here are links for [native](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/connectivity-and-wireless/telephony-information#modem_use) and [web](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/system-information-api-guide) documentation related how to get imei

p.s. as I know, imei(meid) number is available only if wearable is able to connect to  cellular

Answer (score 0):

Since Tizen 2.3 You can use `system_info_get_platform_string()` with  `"http://tizen.org/system/tizenid"` key:

```
char* tizen_id;
int error = system_info_get_platform_string("http://tizen.org/system/tizenid", tizen_id_str);
```